# Tomcat sessions are not cleaned up properly

Tags: java, session, tomcat, tomcat7

we have encountered a memory leak. It occurs whenever the tomcat sessions are not cleaned up properly. One of our created heap dumps is showing 2.5GB in sessions. The log is showing the following:

```
2016-03-10 19:32:34,976 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - D50C0D6ADC7A02B71032E729692D3341.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=101)
2016-03-10 19:32:34,977 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - F552AF04CCA3E5987CA12B3CA707A65B.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=100)
2016-03-10 19:33:35,456 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 9B20DEFCC6AA4B4E83E59D1C9E017EC2.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=99)
2016-03-10 19:33:35,456 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - A56C5E65C5F4230A3699E5B46BEAA5A7.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=98)
2016-03-10 19:33:35,554 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - F7419BD927689F359C4FD9E382CECB35.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=97)
2016-03-10 19:33:35,608 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 86A2EC35561C2A6F6CC33E9279D8D378.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=96)
2016-03-10 19:33:35,608 INFO ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - AFEC9F52D6552569B0D6E3010D0025F7.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=95)
2016-03-10 19:47:39,831 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4652 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 8177FD469930CC8C58A40E1AC05DDF3D.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=121)
2016-03-10 19:47:51,802 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4671 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - C70F96B181343936D9B763AA8E058462.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=123)
2016-03-10 19:47:52,008 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4672 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - AB5A52D70167AB73B50BC15F38CCC555.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=124)
2016-03-10 19:48:19,638 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4688 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - C1171F663AF81155B033090F6A6526F4.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=124)
2016-03-10 19:50:50,764 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4377 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - A78314AFA1A0864F61FBBC8A3F87DDFC.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=132)
2016-03-10 19:51:12,568 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4555 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 34ADDDB2CFF705946160B32B0C3A07E8.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=134)
2016-03-10 19:51:15,115 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4533 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 1697EFBFEE37928D77CB82C403FAAB81.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=134)
2016-03-10 19:51:45,837 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4602 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - BCD0654B34CBEE18AEF8FF72BF13517A.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=139)
2016-03-10 19:53:14,098 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4603 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 62FCB3CBF8F923F0005BD77CB1658B98.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=159)
2016-03-10 19:58:36,482 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4574 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 8CD74088FAB550870ECB6242B1A0DEEC.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=194)
2016-03-10 19:58:54,167 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4601 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - FC91875E280724BD1397D4BC7ED80CF8.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=196)
2016-03-10 19:59:04,894 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4709 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - BEF4DF2EDC5217370679B6C9F06D8BA3.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=197)
2016-03-10 19:59:35,716 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-4723 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 0B5CB30250F81D0AFFAA479E13501DD4.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=205)
```

...
 after a while we are facing around 2k session belonging to just 50 Users.

```
2016-03-10 23:59:36,641 INFO ajp-bio-8010-exec-5973 de.projekt.application.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(150) - SESSION_DESTROYED - 1B086A93D55A748D3E8769A957A06FD0.tomcat02 IS REMOVED(sessions.size=1518)
```

The cleanup of these sessions was working until the ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] thread called the SessionListener.
Suddenly the SessionListener is not called by this thread anymore. Instead it's called by the ajp-bio threads and the amount of sessions is increasing.

Can someone explain to me why all of a sudden the ajp-bio threads are calling the SessionListener instead of the ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] thread?

There are no exceptions in the Catalina out at this time. The tomcat also possesses enough memory.

--EDIT--

web.xml

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: you should have configuration web.xml so that session gets expired automatically after some specified time. In that case there will be no orphan sessions

Comment: session time out can be configured in web.xml and can also be overridden  in code. Sure you are not overriding the web.xml value ?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan In some situations(Logout etc.) the value maxInactiveInterval is set to 1. All SessionObjects in the heap dump have maxInactiveInterval set to 1 or 1800 and the lastAccessedTime was hours ago.

Comment: How does your workers.properties/ajp config look like? It might be a routing problem.

Comment: @Stefan We doesn't have a configuration file for ajp. This is the line in the server.xml <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" /> do we miss here a configuration?

Comment: There is a ".tomcat02" suffix at your session ids. It looked like a balancing setup to me. If you dont use it, you can disable/comment the ajp connector, and see if it chagnes.

Answer (score 0):

you should have configuration web.xml so that session gets expired automatically after some specified time. In that case there will be no orphan sessions

Comment: Session timeout already set to 30min. I have added the session-config to my post.

Comment: is there any ajax call  hitting in background ?

Answer (score 0):

since you have session config to timeout after 30 mins, you need to Test the WebApp and make sure if 1 user logs-in there is only 1 session created.
if there are more than 1 session, you need to track down the code/entity which is creating more sessions.
Note: sessions can be programmatically created, so check if your code is doing it elsewhere.